# PHP mail throughing error

Tags: php, email, smtp

Hi friends I am new to php..
I created one mail function for my live website. (below is my code)
But when i am pressing submit button one error is coming.

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port
>   25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use
>   ini_set() in
>   E:\HostingSpaces\aba0d8c0\smartraysolutions.com\wwwroot\contact.php on
>   line 25

I really don't know how to resolve this issuee....
I am totally blank
I asked my hosting provider about this, so he send me this msg

> Kindly send mails through SMTP authentication. Kindly check below
>   details. Nobody can send mail without authentication or local host,
>   Due to security we have set on authentication bases so you will have
>   to use authentication. Please Use this in your script.
>
> Smtp server name---->mail.yourdomainname.com Smtp port ------->25
>   username-------------->?????@yourdomainname.com
>   password-------------->your Email id password

```
   <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $msg=$_POST['msg'];

        $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
        $headers .= 'From: SmartRay <www.smartraysolutions.com>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

        if(empty("$name") || empty("$email") || empty("$phone") || empty("$msg")){
            $error_msg = "* Please fill all the fields";
        } else {
            // the message
            $full_msg = "Name: " . $name . "\n" . "Email Id: " . $email . "\n" . "Phone No.: " . $phone . "\n" . "Message: " . $msg;

            // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
            $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

            // send email
            //mail("support@smartraysolutions.com","My subject",$full_msg);
            mail("akkii922@gmail.com","My subject",$full_msg,$headers);

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank you for writing us. Our Team will contact you soon!')</script>";

            $sent_msg = "";
            $name="";
            $email="";
            $phone="";
            $msg="";
        }

    }

    ?>
```

plz give me the detailed answer because i am newbee... THANKS

Comment: to use SMTP authentication you can't use php's buit in `mail()`, look at phpmailer or swiftmailer

Comment: Can you give me some example mail code with smtp... if possible.. or modify my code.... I am in trouble... And i really dont know php welll.... But i need to apply mail function in my web page....    Thanks